# Cannot load workspace in VC++6

Tags: visual-c++-6, workspace

I have copied a project to a new directory, and now the workspace will not load into the vc++6 ide.  There is no error, just no workspace.  I have diff'ed the dsw and dsp files, and they are the same.

Answer (score 6):

Well, this is *really* annoying.  The problem turned out to be a CRLF->LF problem in the dsw workspace file.  Git had removed CR's and the diff inside of notepad++ showed identical files.    Add back the CR's and the workspace now loads into VC6.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the project and solution files with a text editor for any paths that point to files that cannot be found - maybe there is a relative or absolute path that cannot be found?

Answer (score 0):

This problem came up when moving from ide-based development to command-line builds and then  back to ide.  The dsw and dsp files need to be newer than the source, or else the workspace will refuse to load.  Just open the files in a text editor and save them without changes, or use touch.exe, which can be had in UnxUtils from sourceforge.